# Google Translate API with android application

Tags: android, google-translate

I created an android application and I'm using Google Translate Rest service.

I used this URL to send a request in order to translate a source text.

```
"https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=" + apiKey + "&target=en&q=" + text"
```

As you can see the source language was not set in order to enable the service to detect
the language of the given text.

When I put something in Hebrew the result I get is question mark.

For example if I enter "שלום עולם" which need to be translated into "hello world" in English,
I get the result "???? ????".

I tried with other languages like Russian or Spanish. It worked fine with Spanish, but 
with the Russian language it worked like Hebrew.

Is there any bug with the API or am I doing something wrong?

**Update:**

```
  encoded = URLEncoder.encode(textToTranslate,"UTF-8");
  url = new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=" + apiKey + "&target=en&q=" + encoded);
```

Thanks,
Elior

Answer (score 1):

You need to encode the text before pass as q parameter.

For example for the string **שלום עולם**:

```
String original = "שלום עולם";
String encoded = null;
try {
    encoded = URLEncoder.encode(original, "UTF-8");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The value of the `encoded` variable will be `%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%9D+%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%9D` and the URL became:

```
"https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=" + apiKey + "&target=en&q=%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%9D+%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%9D"
```

Comment: thanks, it helped to translate from Hebrew, but the other languages like German and Spanish are not being translated right now. When I'm passing the word "welt" in German or "hola" in Spanish I get the input as the result, it doesn't translate them.. is there any other option?

Comment: It's really strange, it should work also with latin chars. What is the result of `URLEncoder.encode` with the words *welt* or *hola*?  They should remain the same as the input. Can you update your question and add the url that you call with the words *welt* or *hola* with and without the `URLEncoder.encode`? Thanks

Comment: You specify the `source` parameter, for this reason it only translate from the Hebrew. Remove `source=he` and it should works

Comment: sorry. it was the wrong url, the problem is when I'm trying to translate from spanish it returns the input i entered, and not the translated word.

Comment: What are the values of `textToTranslate` and `encoded` for the spanish word you want to translate?